# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' while appending array in Swift 2.2

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, nsuserdefaults, swift2

I had to take a few months away from coding and I'm trying to get my apps up to date. After opening this project in Xcode 7.3 I am getting the "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'" error on this line:

```
words.append(storedWords[i] as! String)
```

The whole statement is here:

```
@if let storedWords : AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("customWords") {
        words = []
        for var i = 0; i < storedWords.count; ++i {
            words.append(storedWords[i] as! String)
        }
    }
```

I have seen a few similar questions but the are dealing similar. but different situations. I have tried adapting many of those suggestions, but don't see a direct application to this code. If I am wrong, please point me in the right direction.

This code all worked perfectly before the update and I'm sure its a simple syntax adjustment due to Swift 2.2, but so far nothing has worked.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, that style of for loop is deprecated

Comment: Thanks, I saw that notice in Xcode, once I get this error fixed I need go thru and update all the deprecated code. ;-)

Comment: No problem. Just spreading the good word of Swift 3.0!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be due to the use of `AnyObject`. You probably want to use

```
if let storedWords = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("customWords") as? [String] {
    words = [String]()
    for word in storedWords {
        words.append(word)
    }
}
```

Thus pulling the stored words out of user defaults as an array of strings and iterating over them safely knowing that they must all be strings.

However if this is all you are doing, you can simplify greatly to:

```
let words = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("customWords") as? [String] ?? []
```

Which will set `words` to the array of strings if they exist, otherwise an empty array, no need to iterate just to add all the elements to a new array.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop here? Isn't it the same as words = storedWords ?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I wasn't sure if perhaps the code in the question was a simplified example, so wanted to include an example with a working iteration incase they actually wanted to do something more complicated in the loop. But agreed, in this scenario the loop is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for a quick answer. And for your simplification of my code. I took the for loop from a project I did a year or so ago when I was beginning to learn and just never thought to rework it. Much appreciated!

Comment: @GeorgeGreen ok cool. wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code into latest Xcode 7.3

```
var words = Array<AnyObject>()

    if let storedWords : AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("customWords") {

        words = []

        for i in 0 ..< storedWords.count {

            words.append(storedWords[i] as! String)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for another solution.